# Parsing cloudwatch log event message data using lambda and python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

So... I have lambda that uses python boto3 to pull cloudwatch log streams for me.

```
 responseRDS = client.get_log_events(
    logGroupName='<target log group>',
    logStreamName='<target stream>',
    limit=10,
    startFromHead=False
    )
```

The result I get back is in JSON, however, the data I want to parse is in the message key... which isn't pretty. Here is an example:

```
"message": "# Time: 2020-03-10T05:49:25.597945Z\n# User@Host: domain_XX[domain_XX] @  [11.111.11.111]  Id: 47187\n# Query_time: 36.601863  Lock_time: 0.000237 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 32256
```

All I really want is the Query_time and Rows_examined data. I can think of some dirty ways to do it like parsing the payload using a space as the delimiter... but not really something I want to do if I don't have too. I am hoping there is a way to do it similar to Insights filters where I can just use:

```
@Query_time
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a good use case for a [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re

resp = {"message": "# Time: 2020-03-10T05:49:25.597945Z\n# User@Host: domain_XX[domain_XX] @  [11.111.11.111]  Id: 47187\n# Query_time: 36.601863  Lock_time: 0.000237 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 32256"}

m = re.search(r"Query_time: ([\d.]+).*Rows_examined: (\d+)", resp["message"])
query_time = m.group(1) # 36.601863
rows_examined = m.group(2) # 32256
```

Comment: This looks very promising! I am new to python so I'll have to figure out how to get the regular expressions library into a lambda layer before I can test it.

Comment: Figured out how to import my re layer... but when I execute your code I get "errorMessage": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'",
  "errorType": "AttributeError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 38, in lambda_handler\n    query_time = m.group(1) # 36.601863\n"
  ]

Comment: oops, that was a problem with my code, i updated it to use `re.search` instead of `re.match`, that should work better

Comment: I REALLY appreciate your help JD D, but I hate to say it, all I am getting when I copy and paste this code is: "errorMessage": "Unable to marshal response: <re.Match object; span=(96, 169), match='Query_time: 24.085289  Lock_time: 0.000000 Rows_s> is not JSON serializable",
  "errorType": "Runtime.MarshalError"

Comment: looking at the error message, it appears to be finding it, though.

Comment: m = re.search(r"Query_time: ([\d.]+).*Rows_examined: (\d+)", resp["message"])

Comment: this looks to be an error in your environment or how it's running and not the code itself, what environment are you running this code?  why is trying to serialize the results of `re.search` to JSON?  I am testing this in Python 3.7